# issue decoding json string from curl when chinese characters do not show up properly

Tags: php, json

Having an issue decoding json string, what could be the problem? this curl response returns null after json_decode used

Comment: Try `var_dump(htmlspecialchars($resp));` and tell me what you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try `print_r(json_last_error_msg());`you will receive the following message:

> Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

And from [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)'s manual page:

> This function only works with UTF-8 encoded strings.

So you'll need to convert it first:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://xxx?item_num_id=566056209677');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$converted = mb_convert_encoding($resp, 'UTF-8', 'GB2312');
print_r(json_decode($converted));
```